# Upload image and append it to body with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to make a website builder wherein we have options to add HTML elements
like text, images, videos etc.
For uploading image through the device, I used

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addImage").click(function() {
    $("#fileinput").click();
  });

  $("#fileinput").click(function() {
    $("#fileinput").change(function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
  });

  var x=0;
  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var picture = '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="' + x + 'thImage">'
    $("body").append(picture);
    x=x+1;
  }

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
  <button id="addImage">Upload image</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I linked the function to another button and hid the actual file input button so that it looks good.

**This works fine only for the first time.The nth time I add an image, the image will be added n times.**

**Also, since I am adding images I need an alternate for change() since I may want to add the same image again and again.**

Help me solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with repeated imagery is because you are assigning a new
 `change` event handler on each successive click. Therefore the Nth time you click, N images are appended. You just need to unwrap the `change` event handler from the `click()` event.

Also, to remove the previous image you can append the images to a container and `empty()` that container before adding the next image, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addImage").click(function() {
    $("#fileinput").click();
  });

  $("#fileinput").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });

  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var x = 'foo';
    var picture = '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" style="width:200px;height:200px;" class="' + x + 'thImage">'
    $(".preview").empty().append(picture);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileinput" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
<button id="addImage">Upload image</button>

<div class="preview"></div>
```

Note that `x` was undefined in your original sample. I assumed this was just missing from your question, so simply added a placeholder variable with `foo` as a value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I actually wanted to add multiple images ie. without deleting the previous images.So, I can not add an image to a static div.Also, any idea how to add the same image in successive turns using the function change()?

Comment: That's not how the `file` input works. If you want to upload multiple files from one input add a `multiple="true"` property to the element, however each update will overwrite the previous; you cannot successively append files to the input.

Comment: More like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jpadc82h/ - just remember to add more than one image file when you choose from the file dialog to test it

Comment: Thanks for the new attribute.That would be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it partly did.But I wish I could find an alternate function for change(), something like add() which also works when there is no change in selection

Comment: @SandeepKumarMajji There's no 'out of the box' way to do that with a file input. You could do it manually by adding the chosen files to an array, although you would need some way of storing their file data outside of the file input so you can upload them later on - that's the tricky part.